# Recursive function using lambda expression

Tags: python, recursion, lambda

I need to create a recursive function repeat which takes in a function and uses the function n number of times with the value of x. Here's an iterative version that explains my issue a bit more in detail.

```
def repeat(fn, n, x):
    res = x
    for i in range(n):
        res = fn(res)
        print(res)
    return res

print(repeat(lambda x: x**2, 3, 3)) returns 6561
```

First it takes 3^2, then 3^2^2 which is 81 then again 3^2^2^2 = 6561.
How can i make this recursive so it can work like this.

```
square_three_times = repeat(lambda x: x**2, 3)
print(square_three_times(3)) return 6561
```

I have tried something like this but im really lost and not sure what to do.

```
def repeat(fn, n):
    if n == 1:
        return fn(n):
    else:
        def result(x):
            return fn(n)
    return repeat(fn,result(x))
```

This obviously wouldnt work since the recursion would keep going forever. But im not sure how i should write this code since i first need to calculate 3^2 before taking the next step 9^2 and so on.

Comment: Do you need to make it recursive, or do you need it to work like that? Recursion doesn’t have to be involved.

Comment: I need it to be recursive yes

Comment: Why aren't you using the `x` parameter for your recursive variant?

Comment: If you want a function that only does the repetition implement `repeat(fn, n, x)` and use `functools.partial` to implement the currying.

Comment: filmor: Because it should not work like that, square_three_times is going to contain a lambda function like my example above, which i then can call which number x i want to use to calculate the result.

Comment: For the edit, remove the semicolon from line 3

Comment: @PierreHedkvist: I think you misunderstood filmor's suggestion. If I understood him correctly, he's suggesting that `repeat(fn, n, x)` is easier to write recursively than `repeat(fn, n)`, and then you can turn the three-argument form into a two-argument form that returns a function of `x` trivially with `partial` (as the second version in my answer shows).

Comment: Note that in Python 3.3 the given example in your question returns 81.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Good point, and so does Python 2.7. But I think his code is actually right, and his example just has a simple typo—notice that in the other example, he used `repeat(<square>, 3)`, not `2`. (Which is why copy-pasting a transcript instead of faking it is always a good idea…)

Comment: Yes i meant to write 3 instead of 2 thanks. I changed it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you've got the base case wrong:

```
if n == 1:
    return fn
```

After all, `repeat(fn, 1)` is just a function that applies `fn` once—that's `fn`.

Now, if the base case is when `n == 1`, the recursive case is almost always going to be something where you pass `n - 1` to yourself.

So, what's the difference between `repeat(fn, n)` and `repeat(fn, n-1)`? If you can't figure it out, expand a simple case out in your head or on paper:

```
repeat(fn, 3)(x): fn(fn(fn(x)))
repeat(fn, 2)(x): fn(fn(x))
```

And now it's obvious: `repeat(fn, n)` is the same thing as `fn(repeat(fn, n-1))`, right? So:

```
else:
    def new_fn(x):
        return fn(repeat(fn, n-1)(x))
    return new_fn
```

---

However, as filmor points out in the comments, it would be easier to use `partial` here:

```
def repeat3(fn, n, x):
    if n == 1:
        return fn(x)
    else:
        return fn(repeat3(fn, n-1, x))

def repeat(fn, n):
    return functools.partial(repeat3, fn, n)
```

Comment: Thanks im trying to use your first example but i get invalid syntax on return fn, i edited my original post. EDIT: Never mind, found my silly misstake.

Answer (score -1):

You can define this very simply in terms of your old repeat function:

```
repeat_new = lambda fn, n: lambda x: repeat(fn, n, x)

square_three_times = repeat_new (lambda x: x**2, 3)
print(square_three_times(3))
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not recursive, and the whole point of his question is how to do it recursively. (Plus, that's just a more verbose way of writing `partial`.)

Comment: @abarnert: `functool.partial` only gives you one level of partiality, doesn't it? Is there any easy way with `partial` to turn `f(x, y, z)` into `g(x)(y)(z)`, instead of using `g = lambda x: lambda y: lambda z: f(x, y, z)`

Comment: That's like saying that `lambda` only lets you write one level of partiality explicitly… You can always call `partial` on a `partial`.