# Recursive function using lambda's, why does this not work?

Tags: python, recursion, lambda

I have a function that does some calculation, g(x). I now want to write a function that calculates g(g(g(...g(x)))), where g is applied n times. I tried to do this using `repeat_fn` (see below), but this does not work.

According to [Recursive function using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751635/recursive-function-using-lambda-expression) the solution is to use functools.partial. This does indeed work, but I do not understand how. Also, I do not understand why my approach doesn't work.

```
g = lambda x: 2*x

# Function that returns the fˆn map
def repeat_fn(f, n):
     if n == 1:
         return f
    else:
        return lambda y: f( repeat_fn(f(y), n-1) )


 def repeat_fn_base(fn, n, x):
    if n == 1:
        return fn(x)
    else:
        return fn(repeat_fn_base(fn, n-1, x))

def repeat_fn2(fn, n):
    return functools.partial(repeat_fn_base, fn, n)


j = repeat_fn2(g, 5)
print(type(j))
print(j(2))

k = repeat_fn(g, 5)
print(type(k))
print(k(2))
```

It appears `repeat_fn` is only called once when i use `k = repeat_fn(g, 5)`, while I would expect it to be called five times. Apparently, the recursion doesn't start until I supply k with an argument. Also `print(k(2))` gives the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'function'`.

This surprised me, because e.g. `h = g(g(x)` works just fine.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `return lambda y: f( repeat_fn(f(y), n-1) )`, you are calling `repeat_fn` with the `f` parameter being the result of `f(y)`, i.e. *not* a function. Instead, you should pass just `f` and then apply the result of `fn_repeat` (a function) to `f(y)` (or vice versa).

```
def repeat_fn(f, n):
    if n == 1:
         return f
    else:
        return lambda y: repeat_fn(f, n-1)(f(y))

k = repeat_fn(lambda x: 2*x, 5)
print(k(2))  # 64
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot simpler if you ignore function application; it's just repeated function *composition*:

```
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

def repeat_fn(f, n):
    if n == 1:
        return f
    else:
        return compose(f, repeat_fn(f, n - 1))
```

Note that you can define `repeat_fn` for `n==0` as well, using the identity function `identity = lambda x: x`:

```
def repeat_fn(f, n):
    if n == 0:
        return identity
    else:
        return compose(f, repeat_fn(f, n - 1))
```

This is because `compose(f, identity) == f`.

Comment: Or `reduce(compose, [f] * n)`

Comment: Or `reduce(compose, [f]*n, identity)` to match my update.